# Dojo dijit TabContainer - inline select with tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I'm doing some work on a GUI with a TabContainer (2 tabs) containing two different datagrids.  I found it easiest to just create the tabcontainer divs and datagrids declaratively in html, but I could change that if it would help my problem.  I've been asked if I can put a HTML Select (dijit/form/Select) inline with the tabs of the TabContainer.  Here is a screenshot of a mockup. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVHfR.jpg .  Im not sure if this is possible given how a TabContainer works (being a div), but was wondering if anyone else has done anything similar.  If so, how?

Tabcontainer created like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:964px; height: 450px;"> 
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tasks" data-dojo-props="selected:true">              
        <table id="myDataGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" style="width:964px; height: 420px; ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th field="field1" width="10%">one of many fields for datagrid</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Workers">
        Placeholder...
    </div>
</div>
```

Any examples of placing other dijits inline with the tabs might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried it before but I think this will work.

1) put in the title of the tab container you have a `<div id='Selectid'></div>`

2) use the programmatic way of creating a select form:

```
require(["dijit/form/Select", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Select, win){
    new Select({
        name: "select2",
        options: [
            { label: "TN", value: "Tennessee" },
            { label: "VA", value: "Virginia", selected: true },
            { label: "WA", value: "Washington" },
            { label: "FL", value: "Florida" },
            { label: "CA", value: "California" }
        ]
    }).placeAt('Selectid');
});
```

This should work fine, just make sure the title of the tab is rendering the div with the id correctly.